# Multiple dice throws with "probability gates"

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

You're throwing 6 sided dice and there is 5 "levels" you need to pass. You start at level 1 and to advance to the next level you will need to roll a 6. Once you're on level 2 if you roll a 6 on your first try you will advance to level 3, but if you roll anything other than 6 you will go back to level 1. So in essence you need to pass four 1/6 probability gates to get to level 5. Now the question is, how many throws in total do you need at level 1 to get to level 5? A friend and I have been arguing what is the right way to solve it and we seem to be unable to convince the other that our way is correct.

I deposit that it's a simple as $1/\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)/\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)/\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)/\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$ ~ 1296

My friend argues that it is $\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\right)^x=0.5$ so $^x$ ~ 898

Now to the best of my understanding I am calculating the mean value and he is calculating the median value. I know that median can be better because it "cuts out" outliers, but I'd argue that in this case it should not be used since the data points further away from the median are not random.

Am I right? Is he right? Is neither one of us right? Please explain why mean or median should be used.

Comment: I cannot explain why your answer was wrong because I do not understand how exactly you came upon that answer, but as my answer below shows, $1296$ is the expected number of times that you attempt to leave stage $1$.  You had missed counting the expected number of attempts to leave stages 2 through 4.  Your friend's answer is wrong because it treats a winningstreak as a single throw of the dice and answers the question of "if I repeatedly play this game even after I win, how many times must I be sent back to stage 1 to have at least a 50% chance of having won at least once?"

Comment: I got to $1296$ because even though poorly worded I specifically asked for throws at stage 1, not total amount of throws to get to stage 5. According to your table below $1296$ is the specific answer I was looking for. So my friends equation simply calculates to amount of times he will be "sent" back to stage 1 rather than counting the actual dice rolls?

Comment: As for why I needed the number for stage 1 specifically is because I also need the numbers for stages 2,3 and 4 separately for the purposes I'm actually using this. So thank you for unintentionally providing those also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be described as a markov chain with the following transition matrix with states written in reverse (stage 5 corresponds to first column, stage 4 corresponds to second column, etc...):

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{1}{6}&0&0&0\\
0&0 &\frac{1}{6} &0 &0\\
0&0 &0 &\frac{1}{6} &0\\
0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{6} \\
0&\frac{5}{6} &\frac{5}{6} &\frac{5}{6} &\frac{5}{6} \end{bmatrix}$

This is in standard form $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S\\\hline 0&R\end{array}\right]$

We look to the fundamental matrix $(I-R)^{-1}$ for the information about the expected time until reaching a stationary point.

$I-R = \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{6}&0&0\\0&1&-\frac{1}{6}&0\\0&0&1&-\frac{1}{6}\\-\frac{5}{6}&-\frac{5}{6}&-\frac{5}{6}&\frac{1}{6}\end{bmatrix}$

Using a calculator, $(I-R)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}6&6&6&6\\30&36&36&36\\180&210&216&216\\1080&1260&1290&1296\end{bmatrix}$

We look to the final column since we begin the "game" in stage 1 and add the entries.

The expected number of rolls of the die then will be $6+36+216+1296=1554$

Comment: Also, let's say this game is played on a loop for thousands and thousands of times, is the calculation you provided the "appropriate" one to use instead of what my friend suggests. In essence meaning which is the "appropriate" question to answer in that case.

Comment: @SamiKeronen it depends on what question you want answered... Lets look at a different question.  Suppose you can either win on the first turn with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, on the second turn with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, or if you didn't win either of those two turns you don't get another chance to win until the $597$'th turn at which point it is guaranteed.  Which is more useful to you to know?  That you have at least a $50\%$ chance to win within the first two turns?  Or that if you play this game often enough you will take $200$ turns on average?

Comment: The latter. But my uncertainty becomes from the idea that this type of probability can never be 100% so what 99.999...% will be used as the cut off point to represent that "guarantee" and as such that 597th turn can be 100th or 1000th. No?

Answer (score 0):

You seek the expected number of rolls at level 1 before reaching level 5; call this number $E$. Now, starting from level 1:

- $\frac56$ of the time you don't roll a 6 and you stay on level 1. Now you need an expected $E$ rolls – in addition to the roll you just did – to get to level 5.
- $\frac16\cdot\frac56$ of the time, your first roll is a 6 but your second isn't. Again you return to level 1, and you need an expected $E$ more rolls in addition to the roll at level 1 you just did. This pattern continues for three rolls and four rolls.
- $(\frac16)^4$ of the time, you roll four sixes out of four and reach level 5. You still need a roll at level 1 for this.

Hence we have the following equation for $E$:
$$E=\left(\frac56+\frac5{6^2}+\frac5{6^3}+\frac5{6^4}\right)(1+E)+\frac1{6^4}$$
Solving, we find $E=1296$, i.e. it takes 1296 rolls on average at level 1 to get to level 5, and you are correct.

Comment: As an aside, the mechanics in the background of why this answer works is the same as mine.  I just prefer using the language and machinery of matrices to describe problems such as these out of convenience.

Comment: Thank you, but as you said it takes 1554 rolls in total get to level 5, where as I asked in specific the amount of rolls at level 1, not level 1,2,3 & 4 combined. As per the table provided above by JMoravitz it seems I was correct.

Comment: @SamiKeronen I'm going to edit my answer, please wait a while...

Comment: @SamiKeronen I disagree with that interpretation of the problem/answer... Are you saying that the sequence of rolls $(6,1,6,6,6,6)$ should only count as two rolls instead of six?

Comment: @JMoravitz No, I'm saying that for the actual use of this formula every failed attempt on a specific stage has a value attached to it, based on the stage it happened, and I need to know the different  numbers for stage 1, stage 2, stage 3 and stage 4 separately in order to plug in those different values. For sake of argument let's say every fail at stage 1 gives me 4 gold pieces, at stage 2 that's 8 gold pieces, stage 4 is 24 gold pieces and stage 5 is 120 gold pieces. I need those numbers separate so I can calculate to "total revenue" and compare it to spending. Not real world money though.